# Creating new pandas columns from a pandas column dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Say I have a pandas column that holds dictionaries such that e.g. rows look like this:

```
df[0]['dictionary'] = {'A': 'apple', 'B': 'bucket', 'C': 'cat'}
df[1]['dictionary'] = {'A': 'apple1', 'B': 'bucket1', 'D': 'doggy1'}
```

For each key, value in these dictionaries I want to create a new column with its keyname and corresponding value. So result would look like:

```
      A       B         C       D             dictionary 
0   apple    bucket    cat     None       {'A': 'apple',...}
1   apple1   bucket1   None   doggy1      {'A': 'apple1',...}
```

This is what I tried using `pd.apply` and custom function:

```
def dic_mapper(dic):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        df[k] = v

df['dictionary'] = df['dictionary'].apply(lambda x: dic_mapper(x) if x else None)
```

It seems to have worked at first glance but actually replaced all my column values to be the same. And the original column values are not preserved.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.tolist()`

```
pd.DataFrame(df['dictionary'].tolist())
```

output:

> ```
>         A        B    C       D
> 0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN
> 1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1
> ```

---

P.S. If you want to keep the original column, you can use `pd.concat()` with the original dataframe.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df['dictionary'].tolist()), df], axis=1)
```

output:

> ```
>       A       B         C       D             dictionary 
> 0   apple    bucket    cat     None       {'A': 'apple',...}
> 1   apple1   bucket1   None   doggy1      {'A': 'apple1',...}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('dictionary').apply(pd.Series).add_suffix('_new')], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        A        B    C       D   A_new    B_new C_new   D_new
0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN   apple   bucket   cat     NaN
1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1  apple1  bucket1   NaN  doggy1
```

---

If you don't want to add suffix (but then you will have duplicate column names, which is not what I'd recommend):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('dictionary').apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        A        B    C       D       A        B    C       D
0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN   apple   bucket  cat     NaN
1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
        A        B    C       D                                      dictionary
0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN       {'A': 'apple', 'B': 'bucket', 'C': 'cat'}
1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1  {'A': 'apple1', 'B': 'bucket1', 'D': 'doggy1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_normalize`:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df["dictionary"])

        A        B    C       D
0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN
1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1
```

ETA: If you want to keep the original "dictionary" column as well, use:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df["dictionary"]).join(df)
        A        B    C       D                                      dictionary
0   apple   bucket  cat     NaN       {'A': 'apple', 'B': 'bucket', 'C': 'cat'}
1  apple1  bucket1  NaN  doggy1  {'A': 'apple1', 'B': 'bucket1', 'D': 'doggy1'}
```